# discord.py give role to a certain user id

Tags: discord.py

I'm new to discord.py and I'm a intermediate student, I made a program to give a role to a specific user id, but I encounter some problem that I cannot solve it, anyone can help?

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def change_status():
for number in range(len(data_dict["username"]) - 1):
    if data_dict["year_start"][number] == year_now and data_dict["month_start"][number] == month_now and data_dict["date_start"][number] == date_now:
        userid = int(data_dict["username"][number])
        member = Guild.get_member(userid)
        role = Guild.get_role(840609566093606953)
        member.add_role(role)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the guild object correctly,
You need the line:

```
Guild = client.get_guild(ID)
```

You can find the guild Id by enabling dev mode in user settings and then right clicking on the server name when your server is open